# How to read single characters in a file? Python

Tags: python, loops, file-read

Problem: 
I have to create a program, where the user has to guess a digit after another in pi. 
If he guesses right. It prints correct.
If it's wrong incorrect.
Also it counts the r/w guesses.

The problem I have, is that my code is not jumping to the next digit to guess. *The user is always guessing the same digit.*

**Setup:**

```
pi = open("pi.txt", "r")
name = input("Enter username: ")
print("Hey", name)
seed = len(name)
pi.seek(seed)
digit = pi.read(1)
#guess = input("enter a single digit guess or 'q' to quit: ")
correct_counter = 0
wrong_counter = 0
```

**Loop:**

```
while True:
    guess = input("enter a single digit guess or 'q' to quit: ")
    if guess.isdigit():
        if digit == ".":
            digit = pi.read(1)
        elif digit == "\n":
            seed += 1
            pi.seek(seed)
        else:
            if guess == digit:
                print("correct")
                correct_counter += 1
            else:
                print("incorrect")
                wrong_counter += 1
    else:
        break

print("correct answers: ", correct_counter)
print("incorrect answers: ", wrong_counter)

pi.close()
```

**Output:**

```
enter a single digit guess or 'q' to quit: 1
correct
enter a single digit guess or 'q' to quit: 1
correct
enter a single digit guess or 'q' to quit: 1
correct
enter a single digit guess or 'q' to quit: 1
correct
```

I am very new to coding and this is my first question. So please give me feedback to improve.

Comment: Why do you do `pi.seek(seed)`?

Comment: You need to read the next character in the loop.

Comment: i would guess that the problem is with pi.read(1) line. How is the data stored in this file `pi.txt`

Comment: You're only running the other `if`s after `if guess.isdigit()` - but `\n` is not a digit, so that never gets executed. Yet that's where you `seed += 1`

Comment: @finefoot :That was part of the task

Comment: Thanks all 
@Barmar Thanks it worked now. Had to implement "digit = pi.read(1)" in the loop
now it's working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code, there are only two lines with `pi.read(1)`. Once initially (outside the loop) and then in case of `"."`. However, you need to read a new character each time the user guessed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You start by reading location `1`, which is the decimal point.  Your program advances to the next digit, `1`.  You *never* change `digit` after that.  `pi.seek()` does not change `digit`; you have to read the character there and assign the value again.